# ASP & PHP Web Server on OS X

Tags: macos, apache, php, webserver

On Windows, I ran Xampp on port 80 for PHP/MySQL and IIS on port 8080 for ASP.

For OS X, what's the best route to take...

- Should I just run Xampp for Mac for PHP/mySQL, or is there a better option since this is Unix?
- What's the best (free) way to run ASP off a mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono works relatively well, but some sites built using ASP require Windows-only components (like Windows Forms) that it can't support. I was able to build it but it took some time and hand editing of various dependencies and make files.

As for PHP/MySQL, you do have them already in Mac OS X. You may need to do a bit of leg work to get them working together as you'd like. MAMP and EMAMP are ok, but I almost always run into gotchas when I use them. They're no replacement for a good, stock Apache build with some mods backed up to a text file on Dropbox...

Comment: I think I will end up leaving the ASP run on my Windows box... not worth the work if its not rigorous (I also have MSSQL integrated... it would be a mess to transfer).  With PHP, I'm going to give XAMPP for mac a shot first (because it worked well for me in Win).  I'll check out MAMP if things don't go so well.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it any of them, but there is a port of Mono for Mac that allows you to run ASP.NET on the Mac, and as other users answered there is XAMPP for Mac also.

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX

Answer (score 1):

good news: Abyss will run asp, asp.net, php, and even ruby. 
bad news: it's not designed for professionals; only for nooooobs.

Answer (score 0):

i can answer part of this question - MAMP is made for mac. it stands for Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP and is free. [mamp.info](http://mamp.info) for details. asp... no idea

Comment: you wanted PHP too, right? so MAMP, and something else for ASP

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question you can use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) on mac OS X too.

[image]